# How to put each string into variables from a txt file in batch

Tags: batch-file, text, cmd

I wondering if there is a way to put each string into variables from a txt file in Batch language, like :

Alim.txt  file :

```
381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e   Utilisation_normale

8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c   Performances_élevées

a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a   Économie_d'énergie
```

result:

```
var1=381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e

var2=Utilisation_normale

var3=8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c

var4=Performances_élevées

var5=a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a 

var6=Économie_d'énergie
```

with a count number if possible

In a simple way, I’m not very good in Batchl. I will appreciate any kind of information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the script below:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set _count=0
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%a in ('type Alim.txt') do (
    set /a _count=!_count!+1
    set var!_count!=%%a
    set /a _count=!_count!+1
    set var!_count!=%%b
)
```

### Explanation

- `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` enables delayed expansion to allow setting variables inside a `for` loop.
- `set _count=0` creates a counter variable for setting the variables.
- `type Alim.txt` prints the contents of the `Alim.txt` file.
- `for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%a in ('...') do` loops through each line in `Alim.txt`, splitting them by spaces and saving those parts to `%%a` and `%%b`.
- `set /a _count=!_count!+1` increments the `_count` variable.
- `set var!_count!=%%a` and `set var!_count!=%%b` set a variable based on the current `_count` variable (ex: `var1=381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e`).

## For reference

- [Setlocal - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)
- [Delayed Expansion - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [For /F command - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Set - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)